# QWC2 new theme configuration service genaration from QWC Admin invalid layers

Tags: qgis, qwc2

I'm having the same issue while using QWC Admin to generate service configuration:"CRITICAL: Could not get GetProjectSettings from http://qwc-qgis-server/ows/scan/TestJ: b'\nLayer(s) not valid\n'" TestJ project was created with 3.28 Qgis version, from a blank project, importing just a layer from demo protected_areas.shp file. Enabled Service Capabilities, where I've just defined TestJ short name, saved as qgs file. After copying TestJ.qgs file on "/home/my-user-id/qwc-docker/volumes/qgs-resources/scan/" (with and without TestJ_attachments.zip, zip file and unziped file, db file, shp file, I tried many combinations) the result is always the same.

Comment: Please edit your question to improve the readability of your post. It is unclear what is the specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is you are creating a project with a higher QGIS version than the one handled by the qwc-qgis-server container.

Try to use QGIS LTR version.